# combining two regex expressions

Tags: regex, html, regexbuddy

how can i extract the text from this html snippet...

```
<span id='amount'>&pound;86,950</span></div>
                    <p class="bedrooms">2 bed mews house for sale</p>
                    <h2 class="address">
                        <a href="...31073581.html?showcase=true&premiumA=true">Wilson Street,city 123 
</a></h2>
```

i want to extract

> £86950
>   2 bed mews house for sale
>   Wilson Street,city 123

im using regexbuddy and i can extract value `$pound567849` (via `&pound.*\d`)

i can extract value of next tag via `<p calss.*>.*</p>` (cant use them both together..dont know how to)

but i dont know how to combine  two expressions to get there values collectively...can anybody help plz (sadly new to regex and extracting things)

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one `(?<=(amount|bedrooms)["']>)(.+?)(?=<)` to get array of values

or this one `amount'>(.+?)<.*?bedrooms">(.+?)<` your value would be at group 1 and 2